# could'nt find right parameter for aws_apigatewayv2_route around the "target" Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api

while creating simple aws http api using terraform I couldn't get right approach/ precise parameter to
**api integration scipt**(aws_apigatewayv2_integration)
and **api route** (aws_apigatewayv2_route)

As shown below
[Image for creating http api routes through aws console][1]

[Image for creating Integration through aws console][2]

I could'nt find precise way to do all these stuff using terraform script.

Here are main issues:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "api_b" {
  name          = "api_b"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "testapi" {
  api_id           = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_b.id}"
  integration_type = "AWS_PROXY"

  connection_type    = "INTERNET"
  description        = "Lambda example"
  integration_method = "POST"
  integration_uri    = "${aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.arn}"

}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "example" {
  api_id         = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_b.id}"
  route_key      = "$default"
  operation_name = "ConnectRoute"
  target         = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.testapi.id}"
}
```

As per official documentaion of terraform aws_apigatewayv2_route the target parameter is not well specified:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/apigatewayv2_route.html#target

Hence Kindly give me code / specific syntax for **target**, **route_key**.

Thanks in Advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx8rx.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7WJP.png